# A proper way to say "You are the love of my life" in spanish

Tags: traducción, gramática

I just sent the following whats app message to my girlfriend in Guatemala city :

```
 Mi amor! Te amo mucho.  Tú eres el amor de mi vida.
```

Does it make sense in Spanish? Or is this the proper way to say

```
 My love! I love you so much. You are the love of my life.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm from Spain, so the language may differ a bit, but "te amo" is pretty much a superlative form itself. You can say "te quiero muchísimo", but I think "te amo" has the same meaning, "te amo mucho" doesn't make much sense to me. About the second phrase, omit the "tu".

> ¡Mi amor! Te amo. Eres el amor de mi vida

or

> ¡Mi amor! Te quiero muchísimo. Eres el amor de mi vida

But overall is understandable and correct, she will notice how much you love her :)

Comment: Since OP's girlfriend is Guatemalan, thought I'd mention that 'te amo mucho' is definitely something that could be said here (Guatemala) and it's definitely not unheard of, in fact, it's pretty common among couples.

Answer (score 1):

That makes sense. In spanish, "muchísimo" and "mucho" depends on how excited you are, being the first one the most excited expression.}

I would have texted something like... but anyways you're right.

> Mi amor, ¡Te amo muchísimo! ¡Eres el amor de mi vida!

Answer (score 0):

"Eres el amor de mi vida" is the literal translation.